# MDX Query for TPC H benchmart Query 3

Tags: mdx

Can anyone please guide me with MDX Query for the following query written in SQL-92

```
SELECT TOP 10 
     L_ORDERKEY, 
     SUM(L_EXTENDEDPRICE*(1-L_DISCOUNT)) AS REVENUE, 
     O_ORDERDATE, O_SHIPPRIORITY
FROM 
     CUSTOMER, ORDERS, LINEITEM
WHERE 
     C_MKTSEGMENT = 'BUILDING' 
 AND C_CUSTKEY = O_CUSTKEY 
 AND L_ORDERKEY = O_ORDERKEY 
 AND O_ORDERDATE < '1995-03-15' 
 AND L_SHIPDATE > '1995-03-15'
GROUP BY 
     L_ORDERKEY, O_ORDERDATE, O_SHIPPRIORITY
ORDER BY 
     REVENUE DESC, O_ORDERDATE
```

I have written the following query in MDX but this does not bring results according to Order_Date, I ll share my MDX results with you

```
SELECT {(
    TopCount([TPCHQUERY3VIEW].[L ORDERKEY].members, 
             11, [Measures].[REVENUE]),
    TopCount({null:[TPCHQUERY3VIEW 1].[O ORDERDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00]}, 
             11, [Measures].[REVENUE]),
    [TPCHQUERY3VIEW 2].[O SHIPPRIORITY].&[0])}
    ON ROWS, ORDER([Measures].[REVENUE], [Measures].[REVENUE], DESC) ON COLUMNS
FROM
    [TPC-H 1]
WHERE(
    [TPCHQUERY3VIEW 3].[C MKTSEGMENT].&[BUILDING],
    {null:[TPCHQUERY3VIEW 1].[O ORDERDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00]},
    {[TPCHQUERY3VIEW 4].[L SHIPDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00]:null}
)
```

Comment: Do you have order date members for all dates, or are there dates  which have no orders or shipments? Especially: Can we assume that `[TPCHQUERY3VIEW 1].[O ORDERDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00]` and `[TPCHQUERY3VIEW 4].[L SHIPDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00]` are valid members existing in the cube? Do all date members all have a time component of zero?

Comment: Yes these fields do exist, we're just trying to define a range of date, but there's some syntax error in our query

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with a slightly changed order of result columns, then the following should do:

```
SELECT
    { [Measures].[REVENUE] }
ON COLUMNS,
    TopCount((null : [TPCHQUERY3VIEW].[O ORDERDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00].PrevMember)
             *
             [TPCHQUERY3VIEW].[L ORDERKEY].[L ORDERKEY].Members
             *
             [TPCHQUERY3VIEW].[O SHIPPRIORITY].[O SHIPPRIORITY].Members
             ,
             10,
             [Measures].[REVENUE]),
ON ROWS
FROM
    [TPC-H]
WHERE 
    { [TPCHQUERY3VIEW].[C MKTSEGMENT].&[BUILDING] }
    *
    ([TPCHQUERY3VIEW].[L SHIPDATE].&[1995-03-15T00:00:00].NextMember : null)
```

As I do not have your cube available, I am not absolutely sure there is no missing parenthesis etc. I am not sure why you seem to use different instances of the `TPCHQUERY3VIEW` dimension. I see no need for this. But on the other hand, it seems you do not use different dimensions for customers and orders. Anyway, this is difficult to discuss without seeing the AS cube structure that you built.

`PrevMember` and `NextMember` are needed to match the `<` and `>` logic of the SQL logic, since MDX uses the (in my opinion more natural for end users) inclusive logic of `<=` and `>=`. Furthermore, using order date as the first hierarchy in the `TopCount`, this should implicitly be used as the second sort column, as in case of a tie by revenue, the natural order of the tuples in the set would be kept (MDX [sorting is stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability)).